# Sending emails with smtp python, problem with def block

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, smtplib

I'm new to python, I'm working with python 3. I need to send an email with generated message. Everything is ok with message (I can print it) but somehow in that configuration, with that def-blocks emails aren't sent. What am I doing wrong? I don't get any error notifications.

```
import random
import string
import smtplib

port = 2525 
smtp_server = "smtp.mailtrap.io"
login = "my mailtrap login"
password = "my mailtrap pass"

sender = "from@smtp.mailtrap.io"
receiver = "to@smtp.mailtrap.io"

def randomString(stringLength=10):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))

def randomMessage():
    random_string1 = randomString()
    random_string2 = randomString()

    message = f"""\
    Subject: {random_string1}
    To: {receiver}
    From: {sender}

    {random_string2}"""

    return message

def main():
    with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
        server.login(login, password)
        message = randomMessage()
        #print(message)
        server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: And If you try with another account like gmail?...

Comment: Just to be clear, did you actually write 
`
login = my mailtrap login;
password = my mailtrap pass
`
In your code or it's a string like the other configuration variables?

Comment: @QuantumLicht I like your style. No, I had right variables in code, and that inbox is receiving emails but only if I get rid of string "def main()"

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar I have tried it before but it appears that there are some problems with using gmail as smtp. As I get from other stackoverflow discussions there are some restrictions from gmail

Comment: @Jane with gmail is just some about permission...and you can enable it

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in message type. I changed it to MIMEText and it works now.

```
import random
import string
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

port = 2525 
smtp_server = "smtp.mailtrap.io"
login = "my mailtrap login"
password = "my mailtrap pass"

sender = "from@smtp.mailtrap.io"
receiver = "to@smtp.mailtrap.io"

def randomString(stringLength=10):
    lettersDigits = string.ascii_lowercase + "0123456789"
    return ''.join(random.choice(lettersDigits) for i in range(stringLength))

def makeMessage(subject, content):
    message = MIMEText(content)
    message["Subject"] = subject
    message["From"] = sender
    message["To"] = receiver

    return message

def randomMessage():
    return makeMessage(randomString(), randomString())

def sendMessage(message):
    with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
        server.login(login, password)
        server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message.as_string())
```